# Is Card-io sdk free for android and iphone development?

Tags: credit-card

I am android and iphone developer.I want to use card-io sdk in my own application.I have created  a app token from card-io site.

**I just want to ask if this sdk is free to use or i need to pay card-io some token amount to use it**.

I am going to upload this app on Google play and iTunes store.

Answer (score 0):

Card.io does not charge a monetary fee for use of its service. (See [this Twitter conversation](https://twitter.com/jmpark0521/status/430857036440432640)). This does not mean that it comes without terms or conditions. The terms and conditions are posted here: https://www.card.io/terms/